# Outer div disappears when inner div uses "visible" class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acanou1/dc4htmf4/1/)** for reference.

I'm just getting started with Bootstrap 3 and I don't understand why a div is not behaving the way I want it to. I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="mdgov_TopSliverBar" class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="mdgov_TopSliverBarContent">
            <div id="mdgov_sliverRight">
                <span>Testing</span>
            </div>
            <div id="mdgov_sliverLeft">
                <div id="mdgov_mobileNavButton" class="visible-xs">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars">&nbsp;</i>
                    <span>Menu</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What My Code Does:**

When I resize the window to something other than extra small the "mdgov_TopSliverBar" div disappears and all I'm left with is the word "Testing"- which would be in the right place if the "mdgov_TopSliverBar" div hadn't disappeared.

**What My Code is Supposed to Do:**

When the window is resized I want the "mdgov_TopSliverBar" div to remain along with the "mdgov_sliverRight" div and I want the "mdgov_mobileNavButton" div to disappear. Basically, I should have a black bar at the top with the word "Testing" on the right when the window size is something other than extra small. When the window is extra small I should have the mobile menu icon and the word "Menu" on the left in addition to "Testing" on the right.

Once again, here's the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acanou1/dc4htmf4/1/)** for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the CSS. I needed to get rid of `float: left;` in `#mdgov_sliverLeft` and add `float: right;` in `#mdgov_sliverRight`. So it should look like this:

```
#mdgov_sliverLeft {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#mdgov_sliverRight {
    float: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    right: 2.5%;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
```

Here's the updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acanou1/dc4htmf4/2/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding visible-md and/or visible-sm along with visible-xs - you can nest these classes to get the desired effect.